# Gitlab-CI can't make build loading a package from a VCS repository

Tags: version-control, composer-php, gitlab, git-submodules, gitlab-ci

I'm using gitlab-ci for a repository hosted in gitlab.com and I can't make a build loading a package from a VCS repository.

I use default gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.1.3.

My .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: php:5.6

services:
  - mysql:latest

variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: test
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test

before_script:
  - mkdir ~/.ssh
  - ssh-keyscan -t rsa gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - bash gitlab-ci.sh > /dev/null
  - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  - php composer.phar install
  - cp database/database.sqlite.example database/database.sqlite
  - cp .env.test .env
  - php artisan key:generate
  - php artisan migrate:refresh --seed

test:
  script:
  - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

My composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "description": "Foo",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@gitlab.com:maneko/maravel-pages.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.1",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*",
        "proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation": "1.3.1",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.0",
        "dimsav/laravel-translatable": "^5.5",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
        "maravel/pages": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize",
            "php artisan vendor:publish --provider=\"Proengsoft\\JsValidation\\JsValidationServiceProvider\" --tag=public --force"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error related with access rights and I don't know what else to do. I read to add this in .gitlab-ci.yml file but it didn't work:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`
```

[image]

Any help please??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

the gitlab-ci script is running as a different user. If you've created a key locally and want to use it inside your gitlab-ci you must make the key available for the gitlab-ci.

One way is to copy the file `- cp ~/.ssh/gitlab.com ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

This should copy your local key into the gitlab runner. 
Be aware that the HostKeyChecking by SSH could be a problem sometimes:

Solution

`echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config`
will prevent that.